# Why Im getting response status 0 from httprequests?

Tags: html, gwt, libgdx

Im getting status code 0 when making simple http request (get), even the NetAPITest.java tests are failing. Im testing my app in Google Chrome, with a python temp server pointing to html/build/dist, (After "clean" and "html:dist").

Somebody knows what could be wrong with this?

**Edit:**

This is the most significant part in the console log:

https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.50:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Can you include the console logs from your Chrome dev tools?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I included in the question what seems to be the problem, I think I will make another question, specifically related to this particular error, rather than why it happens

Comment: You should look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource